# Merchant ID versus Gateway Merchant ID

Tags: android, google-pay

The `merchantId` property in the [MerchantInfo](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#MerchantInfo) request object's documentation is marked as required. The description for this property clarifies that it is only required "when [PaymentsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) is initialised with an environment property of [PRODUCTION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)."

Assume that:

1. I initialise [PaymentsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) with an environment property of [PRODUCTION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION);
2. The [TokenizationSpecification](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentMethodTokenizationSpecification) object in my [PaymentDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest) has a `type` of `"PAYMENT_GATEWAY"`; and
3. The [TokenizationSpecification](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentMethodTokenizationSpecification) object in my [PaymentDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest) specifies `"gateway"` and `"gatewayMerchantId"` parameters.

Do I still need to specify a `"merchantId"` value in my [PaymentDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to specify the `merchantId`. The `merchantId` is the one you can find in the Google Pay & Wallet console and is Google specific.

[image]

The `gatewayMerchantId` is something you receive from your Payment Service Provider.